Deducing $\frac{a^2}{c^2} + \frac{b^2}{d^2} = 1$ from $h^2 +k^2 = c^2 + d^2$ and $\frac{a^2h^2}{c^4} + \frac{b^2k^2}{d^4} = 1$
Is there an elegant way to deduce
$$\frac{a^2}{c^2} + \frac{b^2}{d^2} = 1$$
given these equations?
$$\begin{align}
h^2 +k^2 = c^2 + d^2 \tag1\\[5pt]
\frac{a^2h^2}{c^4} + \frac{b^2k^2}{d^4} = 1 \tag2
\end{align}$$
I tried writing comparing the coefficients
$$\frac{c^4}{a^2} = \frac{d^4}{b^2} = c^2 + d^2 \tag3 $$
Context: Here $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive numbers (fixed constants) and $h$ and $k$ are parameters to be eliminated. This was sought as a part of a problem to find the locus of a point.
(See: "A tangent is drawn to the ellipse ..." (via sarthaks.com). In the given solution, it seems to have been got directly without the working being shown.)

The formatting looks pretty clear to me, but if you want actual fractions, you can write \frac{}{} to get a fraction. For example, $\frac{a^2h^2}{c^4}$ produces $\frac{a^2h^2}{c^4}$.

Have added constraints for a, b, c, d. All are positive reals

There are squares floating around, you should reduce the question to $h +k = c+ d$
And $\frac{a}{c^2}h + \frac{b}{d^2}k = 1$ and now it is a classic Simultaneous Linear Equations

This is wrong. Take for example $k=h=1, c^2=\frac32, d^2=\frac12,a^2=\frac98,b^2=\frac18$.

I have added more context, please check now @anankElpis

In the link, it is written that equations $1$ and $3$ hold if $h^2=c^2$ and $k^2=d^2$ which is nothing but equating the terms on both sides.
Notice it does not say that 
equations $1$ and $3$ hold iff $h^2=c^2$ and $k^2=d^2$
It means that you can't prove $\frac{a^2}{c^2} + \frac{b^2}{d^2} = 1
$ for all parameters $h$ and $k$. It is true for certain values only
Now I'm well aware of this examination (I have given it myself) and I know that in this question you only need to select the best option among the given four.
